# break line into multiple textview

Tags: java, android, textview

I have two textview as

```
TEXTVIEW1, TEXTVIEW2
```

And text to be displayed :

```
String line="something ... something ... still continuing ...";  // A very Big Line
```

Firstly I want `TextView1` to be completely filled and then if text overflows, the remaining text is set to the `TextView2`.

My `TextView1` cannot have wrap_content layout dimensionality ie. It has fixed dimensions...

The reason I am looking this is for I want to have something like this

```
IMAGE TEXT TEXT TEXT
      TEXT TEXT TEXT
 TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
```

I have searched through a lot of questions on stackoverflow. There are various ways to do it.

WEBVIEW-- Cant use it as the desired layout forms part of listview

Some project on Github-- Sorry but too complex to use.

Another soln -

```
IMAGE TEXTVIEW1
TEXTVIEW2
```

That interested me a bit so wanted to use it.
If you have any other solution please suggest

Comment: Please help. No active android experts now a days...

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want 2 textviews at all? A textview is capable of extending to as many lines as you could practically want and you shouldn't really be expecting an 'overflow' by default.

Nevertheless, if you really do want to achieve this, you can limit the number of lines in the first textview (android:maxLines). Then you could write some logic to first set the text in textview1, get the text again to check how much actually fit, and then figure out the remaining part left out from your original string and set that to textview2.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Please check out the editted question

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean like this one? Take a look at this library.

https://github.com/deano2390/FlowTextView

[image: hmm]